# Hibernate/JPA DB Schema Generation Best Practices

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I just wanted to hear the opinion of Hibernate experts about DB schema generation best practices for Hibernate/JPA based projects. Especially:

1. What strategy to use when the project has just started? Is it recommended to let Hibernate automatically generate the schema in this phase or is it better to create the database tables manually from earliest phases of the project?
2. Pretending that throughout the project the schema was being generated using Hibernate, is it better to disable automatic schema generation and manually create the database schema just before the system is released into production?
3. And after the system has been released into production, what is the best practice for maintaining the entity classes and the DB schema (e.g. adding/renaming/updating columns, renaming tables, etc.)?

Comment: I guess that such a big problem depends a lot on your project and what is acceptable for it or not:

- central deployment (JEE based for example) vs client-server like

- several client version allowed at any time (=> care on DB col removal, integrity constraints, ...)

- hot deployment vs stop application accepted

- ...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. It's always recommended to generate the schema manually, preferably by a tool supporting database schema revisions, such as the great [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/). Generating the schema from the entities is great in theory, but were fragile in practice and causes lots of problems in the long run(trust me on this).
2. In productions it's always best to have manually generated and review the schema.
3. You make an update to an entity and create a matching update script(revision) to update your database schema to reflect the entity change. You can create a custom solution(I've written a few) or use something more popular like liquibase(it even supports schema changes rollbacks). If you're using a build tool such as maven or ant - it's recommend to plug the db schema update util into the build process so that fresh builds stay in sync with the schema.

Comment: Can you explicit what kind of problems can arise in the long run, especially in production? It'll be extremely useful

Answer (score 14):

Although disputable, I'd say that the answer to all 3 questions is: let hibernate automatically generate the tables in the schema.

I haven't had any problems with that so far. You might need to clean some field up manually from time to time, but this is no headache compared to separately keeping track of DDL scripts - i.e. managing their revisions and synchronizing them with entity changes (and vice-versa)

For deploying on production - an obvious tip - first make sure everything is generated OK on the test environment and then deploy on production.

Comment: But pretend that you have to change your entity relationships in the production environment in a way that will lead to the creation of new tables, and as a result, some data that used to be a part of an old table has to be inserted into these new tables. For example, pretend that you had an entity named Person that had fields for address information and now you want to create a separate entity for holding the address info. This will lead to creation of a new table and you have to migrate the address data from the person table to this new table. But Hibernate cannot do this automatically...

Comment: Personally I strongly advise against this approach. Especially when talking about production. To me there is just not enough control over the process and too much magic going on here.

Comment: Liquibase solves all this 'separately keeping track of DDL scripts - i.e. managing their revisions and synchronizing them with entity changes (and vice-versa)' for you. And you have clear understanding, which changes to db scheme are applied. With automatically table generation you do not have any kind of versioning at all. There are changes that can affect  your data and you may loose them. It is entirely not safe for production, only for dev environment.

Answer (score 8):

Manually, because:

1. Same database may be used by different applications and not all of
   them would be using hibernate or even java. Database schema should
   not be dictated by ORM, it should be designed around the data and
   business requirements.
2. The datatypes chosen by hibernate might not be best suited for the application.
3. As mentioned in an earlier comment, changes to the entities would require manual intervention if data loss is not acceptable.
4. Things such as additional properties (generic term not java
       properties) on join tables work wonderfully in RDBMS but are
           somewhat complex and inefficient to use in an ORM. Doing such a
           mapping from ORM -> RDBMS might create tables that are not
           efficient. In theory, it is possible to build the exact same join
           table using hibernate generated code, but it would require some
           special care while writing the Entities.

I would use automatic generation for standalone applications or databases that are accessed  via the same ORM layer and also if the app needs to be ported to different databases. It would save lot of time in by not requiring one to write and maintain DB vendor specific DDL scripts.

Comment: If you have different applications using the same database it is good practice to have one common API for database interaction which is used by the different applications. Even better you have a webservice that is your interface to the database. Webservice is better because you are language independent. In that way - API or webservice - you have a single point to your database which makes database versioning / ddl changes much easier. This single point could also create and update the database.

Answer (score 5):

Like Bozhidar said, don´t let Hibernate create&update the database schema.
Let your application create and update the database schema. 
For java the best tool to do this is [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org). You need to create one or more SQL files with DDL statements which are describing your database schema. These SQL files are then executed by Flyway. For more information look at the site of [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org).

Comment: Flyway needs a SQL file created manually to do this, it cannot "Let your application create and update the database schema".

Comment: @Bang: Flyway and its SQL File is then part of the application. And therefore it's right to say that the application is creating the database schema.

Comment: Your comment is misunderstanding because you said about " don´t let Hibernate create&update the database schema" so someone think, ok, Hibernate is not good to do this, it is fine, then

"Let your application create and update the database schema. For java the best tool to do this is Flyway"

so Flyway is the best tool to create and update the database schema for application, marvelous, then he checks the website of Flywaydb and disappoint when it requires a Sql file.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a lot of what is being discussed or argued here should also be related to if you are more confortable with the code-first or the database-first approach.

Personally, I am more intended to go for latter and, making a reference to Single Responsibility Principle (SRP), I prefer having DB specialist handling the DB and an application specialist handling the application, than having the application handling the DB. Additionally, I am of the opinion that taking too many shortcuts will work fine at the beginning but create unmanageable problems as things grow/evolve.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Hibernate recommends manual administration for production environments

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-schema