# Hibernate: make database only if not exists

Tags: java, hibernate

I want Hibernate make database file (SQLite), but only if not exists.

Now in hibernate.cfg.xml I have this line:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

The problem is that database file is been creating in all the time, even the file exists.

Comment: I tried this: <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> but it's always creating database.

Comment: So apparently you haven't checked the hibernate manual, which explains the different variants of that option. Please remember that StackOverflow requires you to do a minimum of research yourself before posting a question.

Comment: I wrote a easy solution to follow link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25549938/1736002

You can use 'import.sql' . So, if not exist the database, hibernate creates new db.

Comment: It's pretty clear whats being asked here (unless you don't know Hibernate)! Don't know why this question was closed. The correct and accepted responses are further proof of that.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try switching the value to `update`

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: I tried this on Hibernate 5 inside `persistence-unit::properties` and it didn't create the non-existing table `test` for my `@Entity` with `@Table(name = "test")`.

Comment: Same here. It does not create the database. 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database

Answer (score 37):

Try This:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Difference between `create` and `update` is that, `update` will update your database if database tables are already created and will create if database tables are not created.

And `create` will create tables of database. And if tables are already created then it will drop all the tables and again create tables. In this case your data would be lost.

It is my personal advise to use `update`.