# Can not get data from phpmyadmin SQL with Spring Boot

Tags: php, mysql, spring, jpa

https://github.com/caneraydinbey/JPASQL

As you can see here, i have a table named "Movies" in mysql database in phpmyadmin. I want to get all films,names, (there are 3 films actually). But i get errors.

I have xampp and before i run this application, i run also apache, mysql,proftpd from xammp and i open phpmyadmin page. I dont want to create movie or another table but i want to also add some movies. And i want to get movies from database. Once, it created a table inside database, because wrongly i wrote " movies" instead of "Movies" so it created movies.

My errors are:

```
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Didea.launcher.port=7533 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/caneraydin/Downloads/idea-IU-144.4199.23/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/JPASQL/target/classes:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/caneraydin/Downloads/idea-IU-144.4199.23/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.example.JpasqlApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-03-10 17:26:11.781  INFO 3395 --- [           main] com.example.JpasqlApplication            : Starting JpasqlApplication on caneraydin-270E5J with PID 3395 (/home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/JPASQL/target/classes started by caneraydin in /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/JPASQL)
2016-03-10 17:26:11.805  INFO 3395 --- [           main] com.example.JpasqlApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-03-10 17:26:12.219  INFO 3395 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@27fe3806: startup date [Thu Mar 10 17:26:12 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-03-10 17:26:14.842  INFO 3395 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-03-10 17:26:15.774  INFO 3395 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$beb87713] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-03-10 17:26:16.724  INFO 3395 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-03-10 17:26:16.747  INFO 3395 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-03-10 17:26:16.749  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
2016-03-10 17:26:16.999  INFO 3395 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-03-10 17:26:17.000  INFO 3395 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4786 ms
2016-03-10 17:26:17.735  INFO 3395 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-03-10 17:26:17.751  INFO 3395 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-03-10 17:26:17.753  INFO 3395 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-03-10 17:26:17.753  INFO 3395 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-03-10 17:26:17.754  INFO 3395 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-03-10 17:26:18.543  INFO 3395 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-03-10 17:26:18.569  INFO 3395 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-03-10 17:26:18.717  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-03-10 17:26:18.719  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-03-10 17:26:18.733  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-03-10 17:26:19.185  INFO 3395 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-03-10 17:26:19.969  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-03-10 17:26:20.203  INFO 3395 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-03-10 17:26:21.275  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-03-10 17:26:21.276  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-03-10 17:26:21.283  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-03-10 17:26:21.298  INFO 3395 --- [           main] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: movies
2016-03-10 17:26:21.309  INFO 3395 --- [           main] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: movies
2016-03-10 17:26:21.318  INFO 3395 --- [           main] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: movies
2016-03-10 17:26:21.345 ERROR 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table movies (id bigint not null auto_increment, actors varchar(255), title varchar(255), primary key (id))
2016-03-10 17:26:21.345 ERROR 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : Table 'movies' already exists
2016-03-10 17:26:21.355  INFO 3395 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-03-10 17:26:22.369  INFO 3395 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@27fe3806: startup date [Thu Mar 10 17:26:12 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your hibernate config properties, and make sure you are using this

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

rather than this:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

See this post for more info: [Hibernate: make database only if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788068/hibernate-make-database-only-if-not-exists)

Comment: I dont have hibernate, when i go to project structure-modules. There is only spring. But at first, i chose hibernate. While creating spring initializt project?