# Spring Boot JPA CrudRepository error table not found

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to set up a simple Hibernate + Spring JPA repository example in my project. I am using an oracle database, for reference.

I have a simple entity declares as follows

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long Id;
    
    private String name;
    private String detail;
    
}
```

When running the project, hibernate creates a table named `hte_item` in oracle.

I have set up a controller which tries to fetch all the items in the table. I have created the following repository

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
    List<Item> findAll();
}
```

When running `itemRepository.findAll`, instead, Spring JPA runs the following query to the database.

`select i1_0.id,i1_0.detail,i1_0.name from item i1_0`

Which throws an Oracle error `ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist`

If you notice, the query does not include the prefix generated by Hibernate, which generates the Oracle error. Am I missing something related to configuration here?

Comment: Why don't you create the table by yourself before executing the spring program?

Comment: Check entity, you have name table as `item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'hte' prefix means that it's a temporary table generated by hibernate. It's not the table for your entity.

Basically, you need to create your table, either manually or through some automated process.  See, for example, [How to create database schema in hibernate first time and further update it in case of schema modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815037/how-to-create-database-schema-in-hibernate-first-time-and-further-update-it-in-c/19852151#19852151)

Comment: Thanks, obviously I haven't grasped enough of Hibernate yet, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> When running the project, hibernate creates a table named `hte_item` in oracle.

The `hte_item` table is a temporary table used by Hibernate for certain bulk update and delete queries. It is *not* the name of the table where `Item`s are made persistent.

Since you've specified `@Table(name = "item")` you must have a table named `item` in your database. If you want Hibernate to export that table for you, then you need to explicitly enable schema export, by setting a config property:

```
jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=create
```

or whatever.