# relationship and build database

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entity-relationship

For an excercise I need to build something like :

For a course I need to create a review that is made up out of certain reviewlines and feedbackscores.

This review object (unique instance) needs to be filled in by a list of customers.

Depending on the course the review is for, the review will change (e.g.for one course the number of reviewlines and feedbackscores will change).  Each customer can be enrolled in more then one course and each review is specific for him.

[image]

Now how do I need to see the relationsship between "review" object (unique instance) and "customer" if I want to use JPA to save this all to the db?

- A customer can have more then one review he/she needs to fill in.
- A certain review object needs to be filled in by many customers (but this is a review object with a certain build [reviewlines and feedbackscores]) and unique for him.

Maybe I see it to complex but what is the best way to build this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

[image: ER/Class diagram]

I think it's covered all your design points.

I am trying to read between the lines of your comments, and I think you want to implement a system where you capture a number of 'rules' for the `Review` (I'm guessing, but examples may be that reviews can be up to *n* lines, there must be at least *m* `CustomerReviews` before the `Review` gains a degree of quality). If this is indeed the case, I have created a `ReviewTemplate` class:

- `ReviewTemplate` would have attributes/columns for each of value you would need. These attributes/columns are *duplicated* on `Review`
- Populate `ReviewTemplate` with a number of rows, then create a row in `Course` and link it to one `ReviewTemplate`
- When a `Course` needs a `Review`, *copy* the fields from the `ReviewTemplate` into the `Review`
- In Java, implement the business rules for `Review` using the *copied values* - not the values on `ReviewTemplate`.

Why copy the values? Well, I bet that at some point, users want to edit the `ReviewTemplate` table. If so, what happens to the `Review` objects using the edited `ReviewTemplates`? Does the modified value on `ReviewTemplate` somehow invalidate past `Reviews` and break your business logic? No, *because you copied the rule values* to `Review` and so past `Reviews` will not change.

**EDIT: Answers to specific questions**

> How do you see the duplicating? I can create an entity ReviewTemplate with the specified attributes. In this entity there will be a relationship with reviewlines and feedbackscores.

I see each `ReviewTemplate` as holding prototypical values for a particular 'type' of `Review`, which just might include a default reviewLine (but that might not make sense) and a default feedbackScore. When you create the `Review`, you would do the following:

1. Instantiate the `Review` and populate with values from `ReviewTemplate`
2. Instantiate as many `CustomerReview` objects as you need, linking them to the relevant `Customer` objects (I infer this step from your previous comments. It might also make sense to omit this step until a `Customer` voluntarily elects to review a `Course`)

   1. (If appropriate) Populate the `CustomerReview` attribute `feedbackScore` with the default value from `ReviewTemplate`
   2. Instantiate `CustomerReviewLine` records as appropriate

If you follow this approach, you do not need to add a relationship between `ReviewTemplate`  and `CustomerReviewLines`.

> When I e.g. state that customers 1 to 4 need to fill in the review 4 specific "objects" need to be created that will hold the information and also 4 sets of the needed reviewlines and feedbackscores need to be created so they all can hold the information.

Absolutely.

> I just don't know how to implement this is a JPA structure so the information is hold in the db ... ?

JPA allows you to attack the problem in many ways, but the best practice is to manually create both the DB schema and the Java classes (eg see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585763/1395668). Therefore, for each entity in the diagram, you need to:

1. Write SQL DDL statements to create the table, columns, primary key and foreign keys, and
2. Write a Java class denoted with the `@entity` annotation. Within the class, you will also need to annotate the id (primary key) with `@id` and the relationships with `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` (theirs additional parameters in the annotation to set as well).

Now, on the JPA side, you can do things like:

```
ReviewTemplate template = course.getReviewTemplate(); //assuming the variable course
Review review = new Review();
review.setCourse(course);
review.setRuleOne(template.getRuleOne());
// Copy other properties here

EntityManager em = // get the entity manager here
em.persist(review);

// Assume a set or list of customers
for (Customer customer : customers) {
    CustomerReview cr = new CustomerReview();
    cr.setReview(review);
    cr.setCustomer(customer); 
    cr.setFeedbackScore(template.getDefaultFeedbackScore());
    // set other CustomerReview properties here

    em.persist(cr);

    // You can create CustomerReviewLine here as well
```

If written inside a standard EJB Session Bean, this will all be nicely transacted, and you will have all your new records committed into the DB.

**EDIT 2: Additional question**

(I'm assuming that the second comment completely supersedes the first)

> So when I create a reviewtemplate and I link it to a bunch of customers I write the template to the db and create a bunch of reviews based on the template but linked to the specific customer and with his own unique reviewlines and feedbackscores. Like I see it now the reviewline (more a question or discription) is the same for each review (of a template), it is only the score that changes between the customers

I finally think I understand `ReviewLine`. I had thought it a place where the `Customer` enters lines of text the comprise the `CustomerReview`. I now believe that `ReviewLine` is a specific question that the `Customer` is asked, and which the `Customer` provides a feedbackScore.

With this understanding, here is an updated ER/Class diagram.

[image]

Note that there are some significant changes - there are several more tables:

1. `ReviewLineTemplate` provides a place for template questions to be stored on a `ReviewTemplate`
2. When a `Review` is instantiated/inserted (which is a copy of a specific `ReviewTemplate`), the `ReviewLineTemplates` are copied as `ReviewLines`. The copy operation allows two important features:

   1. On creation, a `Review` and its `ReviewLines` can be customized without affecting the `ReviewTemplate` or `ReviewLineTemplate`
   2. Over time, the `ReviewTemplate` and `ReviewLineTemplate` can be updated, edited and continually improved, *without changing the questions that the `Customer` has already answered*. If `CustomerFeedbackScore` were linked to `ReviewLineTemplate` directly, then editing the `ReviewLineTemplate` would change the question that the `Customer` has answered, silently invalidating the feedbackScore.
3. FeedbackScore has been moved to a join-table between `ReviewLine` and `CustomerReview`.

Note that this model is fully denormalised which makes it more 'correct' but harder to build a GUI for. A common 'optimization' might be to introduce:

- 10 (say) columns on `ReviewTemplate` and `Review` called `reviewLine1` through `reviewLine10`.
- 10 (say) columns on `CustomerReview` called `feedbackScore1` through `feedbackScore10`.
- Remove the `ReviewTemplateLine`, `ReviewLine` and `CustomerReviewLine` tables

Doing so *is not normalised*, and may introduce a set of other problems. YMMV

Comment: How do you see the duplicating? I can create an entity ReviewTemplate with the specified attributes. In this entity there will be a relationship with reviewlines and feedbackscores. When I e.g. state that customers 1 to 4 need to fill in the review 4 specific "objects" need to be created that will hold the information and also 4 sets of the needed reviewlines and feedbackscores need to be created so they all can hold the information I just don't know how to implement this is a JPA structure so the information is hold in the db ... ?

Comment: First of all thx for the reply.  I'm still not with you.  I create a class/entity reviewTemplate.  The difference between te templates are the number of and values of the reviewlines and feedbackscores. Depending on the amount of lines I could create a review with the specified amount of lines and the value's of the template (e.g. name, startdate, ..) Why do I not need to create a relationship between review and lines.  The lines are not in the review and unique for each object so I do need to link those and write the to the db so I can retrieve them? I hope this makes any sense

Comment: So when I create a reviewtemplate and I link it to a bunch of customers I write the template to the db and create a bunch of reviews based on the template but linked to the specific customer and with his own unique reviewlines and feedbackscores.  Like I see it now the reviewline (more a question or discription) is the same for each review (of a template), it is only the score that changes between the customers.

Comment: First of all, thx again for all the effort.  True, you see it right!  I now see the reviewlines as a number of questions in the template the customer need to set a feedbackscore to.  Because all the reviewlines are the same for all the customers and only there feedbackscores are different this solution is usable.  I agree the normalisation is a total different issue ... .  But first of all, I will try to get this working because the excercise is more from a JPA, servlet, jsp perspective ... .

Answer (score 1):

The structure of data always depends on the requirements, and there never exists a "one-and-only" solution. So, do you need maximised atomiticy or a high performance data system?

The fastest and easiest solution would be not using a database, but hash tables. In your case, you could have something like 3 hash tables for customer, review, and probably another one for the n:n relationship. Or if you're using a database, you could just store an array of the review-primary-keys in one field in the customer table.

However, we all learn in school to do atomicity, so let's do that (I just write the primary/foreign keys!):

- Customer (unique_ID, ...)
- Review (unique_ID, ...)
- Customer_Review (customer_ID, review_ID, ...) --> n:n-relationship

The Customer_Review describes the n:n-relationship between customers and reviews. But if there is only one customer per review possible, you'll do that like this:

- Customer (unique_ID, ...)
- Review (pk: unique_ID, fk: customer_ID, ...) --> 1:n-relationship

However, I suggest you need to learn ERM as a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_relationship_model

Answer (score 0):

You need a ManyToMany relation :

- One customer -> several reviews.
- One review -> several customers.

So you will have 3 tables in your database schema : Customer, review and a junction table with the customer ID and the review ID.

See [Wikipedia : Many to Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

Comment: The problem with this is that if I build a review with revieuwlines and feedbackscores.  This review object needs to be filled in by the customers.  But each customer needs to fill in his own review object.

Comment: Where's your problem ? The junction table will permit 2 operations : Getting the reviews assiciated with a particular Customer, and getting the customers who need to fill a particular review.

Comment: For example : I create a review object with 5 reviewlines and feedbackscores. This review needs to be filled in by customer 1 to 4. I create another review object with 3 reviewlines and feedbackscores. This review need to be filled in by customer 1 to 3. for each customer the specific review is unique. It's not something like a book can have many authors and a author has many books (here the book stays the same). In this case the specific review needs to be filled in by the specific customer. it's not one review that is linked to many customers

Comment: Ok, are you trying to say that a reviewline is what is created when a customer fills in the review ? If it's ok, the reviewline table should have a Many-to-One relation with customers. This is to retrieve the author. The Many-to-Many link between customers and review doesn't provide an "author" information, but a "have to fill in" information.
I'm sorry, my english is not very good but I do my best to understand you.

Comment: I mean if you have like a many to many between Book and author (a book can have 1 or more authors and a author can have zero or more books he has written) you speak over the same book and the same author for this relationship.  In this case if I make a review (with his collection of reviewlines and scores) this is more like a review type.  This review type must then be duplicated over the amount of customers you want to have that the list of customers need to fill in.  Each customer has a specific review only he need to fill in.  Another custormer has nothing to do with his review

Comment: The problem is that not each reviewtype is the same.  A review over something will have some reviewlines another revieuw will have other review lines.  So I think it will be better to create a reviewtype and then create reviews of a certain type that I link to the customers.  If a customer need to fill in another reviewtype I need to create a new type and create reviews of this type and link this again to those customers that must fill in this review.  Another solution is not possible because the fact that not all reviews are the same, only those of a certain "type".