# Why do we need to create databases while we can generate them using Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am wondering why do we need to create databases with Oracle or MySQL while we can use ORMs such as Hibernate to easily generate them ?

Answer (score 3):

Just taking an extract from the related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585641/hibernate-jpa-db-schema-generation-best-practices):

- It's always recommended to generate the schema manually, preferably
  by a tool supporting database schema revisions, such as the great
  [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). Generating the schema from the entities is great in
  theory, but were fragile in practice and causes lots of problems in
  the long run(trust me on this).
- Same database may be used by different applications and not all of
  them would be using hibernate or even java. Database schema should
  not be dictated by ORM, it should be designed around the data and
  business requirements
- additional properties (generic term not java properties) on join
  tables work wonderfully in RDBMS but are somewhat complex and
  inefficient to use in an ORM. Doing such a mapping from ORM -> RDBMS
  might create tables that are not efficient. In theory, it is possible
  to build the exact same join table using hibernate generated code,
  but it would require some special care while writing the Entities

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I have much more control using the traditional RDBMS over ORMs. Testing is easier using a rdbms when designing/implementing your schema.